# Search a element in file and print whole line

Tags: c, file

I have a file with these contents:

```
Code                Name     Income    Allow      Pens     Ins    Depend    Charity    Taxable       Tax       Net
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 008                John     100000     4000      5000    1000      3200       1000      85800     20280     79720
 001                 Doe      50000     4000         0     500      1600          0      43900      7725     42275
```

I want to print a record if the input code is same as the code in the file.
This is my code:

```
fscanf(fp, " %3d%s%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf", &code_t, buffer, &inc_t, &personal, &pension_t, &health_t, &depend_t, &gift_t, &taxable_t, &tax_t, &net_t);  
printf("\n");
printf(" 03d%20s%11.0lf%9.0lf%10.0lf%8.0lf%10.0lf%11.0lf%11.0lf%10.0lf%10.0lf\n", code_t, buffer, inc_t, personal, pension_t, health_t, depend_t, gift_t, taxable_t, tax_t, net_t);
                `
```

but it doesn't work.
So I'm thinking about using `fscanf` to read only the code and then print the line which contains that code. But how can I read the code without other contents like `Name`, `Income`, ... and how to read if the code has leading 0 like that?

Comment: Quote: "...but it doesn't work." Could you me more specific?

Comment: Have you checked the return value from `fscanf`? How many input items was successfully matched?

Comment: the _scanf_ is ok after bypassing the 2 first lines of the file, there is however a missing % in the _printf_ producing a crash because the code is used as a string because of that. See my answer

Comment: It is very confusing (and incorrect) to name your variables with `_t` as they are reserved by the standard for defining types such as  `size_t`, `uint8_t`, wchar_t etc.

Comment: @Dipstick thanks for that. i just use them temporarily to test my program and i will edit them later

Comment: @4386427 I didn't think about the first two lines. Maybe they caused the reading's error

Comment: @bruno actually that was my typing mistake when typing question, but not in my source code. thanks for your answer.

Comment: @savethesavior Well it's not "Maybe they caused the reading's error" It is "they **did'' cause the reading's error". Non of the first two lines can match `%d` to start with so nothing is scanned. In general avoid `fscanf` and use `fgets`together with `sscanf`. That will give you much better control.

Comment: @4386427 Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you cannot read the file with its header using the *scanf* you give because *Code* is incompatible with the first `%d`, so you need to bypass the first 2 lines

Warning a `%` is missing in your *printf* to print the code, so the code is considered as the string by `%s` with an unspecified behavior (a crash generally)

> But how can I read the code without other contents like Name, Income

Of course if you use your *scanf* you also read the other fields, is it a real problem ? You can also read line per line as a strings (*fgets* or *getline*) and look at the beginning if you have the expected code and in that case manage the rest of the string to extract the fields if needed etc

An other way if the content of the file is very formatted is to change the file pointer using *fseek* to only read the codes up to the expected one (see the proposal at the end of my answer).

> how to read if the code has leading 0 like that?

I do not understand *scanf* read it well, this is not octal because there is 008. If the presence of the 0 at the left are important do not manage the code as a number but as a string both in the file and when the code to search is given

---

A code from yours reading well your input file :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bypassLine(FILE * fp)
{
  int c;

  for (;;) {
    c = fgetc(fp);

    if (c == EOF)
      return 0;
    if (c == '\n')
      return 1;
  }
}

int main()
{
  FILE * fp = stdin;
  int code_t;
  char buffer[64];
  double inc_t, personal, pension_t, health_t, depend_t, gift_t, taxable_t, tax_t, net_t;

  if (!bypassLine(fp) || !bypassLine(fp))
    puts("too short file");
  else {
    while (fscanf(fp, " %3d%s%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf", &code_t, buffer, &inc_t, &personal, &pension_t, &health_t, &depend_t, &gift_t, &taxable_t, &tax_t, &net_t) == 11) {
      printf(" %03d%20s%11.0lf%9.0lf%10.0lf%8.0lf%10.0lf%11.0lf%11.0lf%10.0lf%10.0lf\n", code_t, buffer, inc_t, personal, pension_t, health_t, depend_t, gift_t, taxable_t, tax_t, net_t);
    }
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra f.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat f
Code                Name     Income    Allow      Pens     Ins    Depend    Charity    Taxable       Tax       Net
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
008                John     100000     4000      5000    1000      3200       1000      85800     20280     79720
001                 Doe      50000     4000         0     500      1600          0      43900      7725     42275
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out < f
 008                John     100000     4000      5000    1000      3200       1000      85800     20280     79720
 001                 Doe      50000     4000         0     500      1600          0      43900      7725     42275
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Note there is no protection against an overflow when reading the string in *scanf* with just `%s`, if is better to use `%63s` because I sized *buffer* 64

---

A little change to search for the code, still using your *scanf*, giving the name of the file and the expected code in argument :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bypassLine(FILE * fp)
{
  int c;

  for (;;) {
    c = fgetc(fp);

    if (c == EOF)
      return 0;
    if (c == '\n')
      return 1;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  if (argc != 3)
    printf("usage : %s <file> <code>\n", *argv);
  else {
    FILE * fp;
    int code_t, expected;
    char buffer[64];
    double inc_t, personal, pension_t, health_t, depend_t, gift_t, taxable_t, tax_t, net_t;

    if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "cannot open '%f'\n", argv[1]);
      return -1;
    }

    if (!bypassLine(fp) || !bypassLine(fp)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "too short file '%s'\n", argv[1]);
      fclose(fp);
      return -1;
    }

    if (sscanf(argv[2], "%d%c", &expected, buffer) != 1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "invalid code '%s'\n", argv[2]);
    }
    else {
      while (fscanf(fp, " %3d%63s%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf", &code_t, buffer, &inc_t, &personal, &pension_t, &health_t, &depend_t, &gift_t, &taxable_t, &tax_t, &net_t) == 11) {
        if (code_t == expected) {
          printf(" %03d%20s%11.0lf%9.0lf%10.0lf%8.0lf%10.0lf%11.0lf%11.0lf%10.0lf%10.0lf\n", code_t, buffer, inc_t, personal, pension_t, health_t, depend_t, gift_t, taxable_t, tax_t, net_t);
          fclose(fp);
          return 0;
        }
      }
      fprintf(stderr, "code %d not found in '%s'\n", expected, argv[1]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra f.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out ./f 2
code 2 not found in './f'
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out ./f 8
 008                John     100000     4000      5000    1000      3200       1000      85800     20280     79720
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

---

An other way using *fseek* to move directly from code to code in the file :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bypassLine(FILE * fp)
{
  int c;

  for (;;) {
    c = fgetc(fp);

    if (c == EOF)
      return 0;
    if (c == '\n')
      return 1;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  if (argc != 3)
    printf("usage : %s <file> <code>\n", *argv);
  else {
    FILE * fp;
    int code_t, expected;
    char buffer[64];
    double inc_t, personal, pension_t, health_t, depend_t, gift_t, taxable_t, tax_t, net_t;

    if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "cannot open '%f'\n", argv[1]);
      return -1;
    }

    if (!bypassLine(fp) || !bypassLine(fp)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "too short file '%s'\n", argv[1]);
      fclose(fp);
      return -1;
    }

    if (sscanf(argv[2], "%d%c", &expected, buffer) != 1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "invalid code '%s'\n", argv[2]);
    }
    else {
      long offset = ftell(fp);

      while (fscanf(fp, " %03d", &code_t) == 1) {
        if (code_t == expected) {
          /* extract the other fields */
          if (fscanf(fp, "%63s%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf", buffer, &inc_t, &personal, &pension_t, &health_t, &depend_t, &gift_t, &taxable_t, &tax_t, &net_t) == 10) {
            printf(" %03d%20s%11.0lf%9.0lf%10.0lf%8.0lf%10.0lf%11.0lf%11.0lf%10.0lf%10.0lf\n", code_t, buffer, inc_t, personal, pension_t, health_t, depend_t, gift_t, taxable_t, tax_t, net_t);
            fclose(fp);
            return 0;
          }
          else {
            fprintf(stderr, "code %d found but cannot read next fields\n", code_t);
            fclose(fp);
            return -1;
          }
        }
        /* the lines are supposed having all the times 114 characters newline included */
        offset += 114;
        if (fseek(fp, offset, SEEK_SET) == -1) {
          fprintf(stderr, "error when going at offset %d of '%s'\n", offset, argv[1]);
          fclose(fp);
          return -1;
        }
      }
      fprintf(stderr, "code %d not found in '%s'\n", expected, argv[1]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra f.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat f
Code                Name     Income    Allow      Pens     Ins    Depend    Charity    Taxable       Tax       Net
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
008                John     100000     4000      5000    1000      3200       1000      85800     20280     79720
001                 Doe      50000     4000         0     500      1600          0      43900      7725     42275
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out ./f 8
 008                John     100000     4000      5000    1000      3200       1000      85800     20280     79720
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out ./f 1
 001                 Doe      50000     4000         0     500      1600          0      43900      7725     42275
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out ./f 11
code 11 not found in './f'
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I didn't realize that those titles make the data impossible to read without skipping them.

Comment: @savethesavior yes, when the input is invalid for _scanf_ (depending on the %xx) the invalid input stay **unread**, it is not bypassed. Hope the other tips in my answer can help you too. Happy coding ;-)

Comment: One more question. Is it possible to skip the first 2 lines by using fgets?

Comment: @savethesavior of course, if you are sure to know their maximum length, I did _fgetc_ to not have that problem and because this is more efficient than the _fgets_ whose copy the line in the string while you do not need that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to print a record if the input code is same as the code in the file.

If your goal is simply to print the records (aka lines) where "Code" matches some value given by the user, your approach seems a bit too complex as there is no need for scanning all the fields.

Simply use `fgets` to read the line, then check the Code value and do the print if it matches.

Something like:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  if (argc != 2)
  {
    printf("Wrong usage...\n");
    return 1;
  }
  int code_to_print = atoi(argv[1]);
  int code_read;

  FILE* fp = fopen("db.txt", "r");
  if (!fp)
  {
    printf("File error...\n");
    return 1;
  }
  char buf[1024];

  while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp))
  {
    if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &code_read) == 1 && code_read == code_to_print)
    {
      printf("%s", buf);
    }
  }
  fclose(fp);
}
```

Use the program like:

```
./prog 8
```

> .. how to read if the code has leading 0 like that?

If the leading zeros are important then you can't scan using `%d` as that will "remove" the zeros. Instead you need to scan the Code as a word. Like:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  if (argc != 2)
  {
    printf("Wrong usage...\n");
    return 1;
  }

  char code_read[4] = {0};

  FILE* fp = fopen("db.txt", "r");
  char buf[1024];

  while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp))
  {
    if (sscanf(buf, "%3s", code_read) == 1 && strcmp(code_read, argv[1]) == 0)
    {
      printf("%s", buf);
    }
  }
  fclose(fp);
}
```

Use the program like:

```
./prog 008
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution !